# TA-Lib Windows 10 install

Tags: ta-lib

I am trying to install `TA-Lib` locally on my Windows 10 machine and keep receiving the following error:

> ERROR: TA_Lib-0.4.18-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on >this platform.

I am running Python 3.8, and Windows 10 is 64 bit.  I have tried upgrading pip, but this does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

TA-Lib is a C-library with python wrapper. Firstly, install the C library binary, then install python wrapper. Check out Dependencies section at https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html

Comment: I believe TA_Lib-0.4.18-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is the dependency :)